# Python event has not Key attribute

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a program for when my character moves. here is my code

```
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if(event.key == K_RIGHT):
            playerPos[0] +=1
    if (event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH -1:
        playerPos[0] =+ 1
```

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\python things\firstgame.py", line 90, in <module>
if (event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH -1:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: Oh terribly sorry, this is my movement code, so whilst in the game, I press the right arrow on the keyboard, the character moves right. and if he is on the edge of the map it wont let the character move to the right anymore @Davy M

Comment: you can also probably combine your two `if` statements together like `if(event.type == KEYDOWN) and (event.key == K_RIGHT):`

Comment: I would imagine that your last `if` statement should not be there. Instead you should make the `playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH -1` condition part of the above `if` statement. You will not have an `event.key` unless `event.type == KEYDOWN` I guess.

Comment: @JohanL thats it! thank you!!

Comment: that would work because it got rid of the problematic if statement that is outside the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone comes across this post and had same issue, I fixed my error and ended up with this. added comments to help others understand

```
while True:
    #get all the user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #if user wants to quit
        if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:
            #and the game close the window
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        #if a key is pressed
        elif event.type == pygame.locals.KEYDOWN:
            #if right arrow is pressed
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                #change player's x postion
                playerPos[0] +=1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                #change player x position
                playerPos[0] -=1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[0] > 0:
                #change players x position
                playerPos[1] -=1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT -1:
                #change player x position
                playerPos[1] += 1
```

Comment: The code after the for loop should be indented one more level. Indention is important in Python so make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `if (event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH -1:`
is outside of the forloop so the event doesn't have a key attribute.

the event inside the forloop has a key attribute because of `pygame.event.get():` move that line inside of the forloop and that should solve your problem.

```
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
       elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if(event.key == K_RIGHT):
            playerPos[0] +=1
       elif (event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH -1:
            playerPos[0] =+ 1
```

I would also suggest you combine line 87 and 88 into one like such
`elif(event.type == KEYDOWN) and (event.key == K_RIGHT):`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to check what type of event is. In pygame only the `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` events have a key attribute. So it will work if you do this:

```
if event.type == event.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == event.K_RIGHT:
        playerPos[0] += 1
```