# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

I get the error message below when I run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/MyDevWork/PygamesRelated/game_1.py", line 29, in <module>
    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (32, 32))
image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
image.fill(WHITE)

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                rect.move_ip(0, -2)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            rect.move_ip(0, 2)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            rect.move_ip(2, 0)

screen.fill(BLACK)
screen.blit(image, rect)
pygame.display.update()
```

I am using python 3.7 and Pycharm.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The line `elif event.key == pygame.K_s` and the like should be at the same level as `if event.key == pygame.K_w`.

Comment: related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983710/python-event-has-not-key-attribute)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned, your indentation is the problem here. Everything checking the `event.key` should be "inside" the `KEYDOWN` check. Change your while loop to:

```
while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                rect.move_ip(0, -2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                rect.move_ip(0, 2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rect.move_ip(2, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you StardustGogeta and Akaisteph7. Wrong indentation was actually the cause of my problem. I followed your advice and the problem is solved. Once again, thanks.